# OOP philosophy (an extract on composition and inheritance from Programming in Scala)

Tags: oop, scala, inheritance, architecture, composition

In Programming in Scala, page 239, the first paragraph says:

> Composition and inheritance are two ways to define a new class in
>   terms of another existing class. If what you’re after is primarily
>   code reuse, you should in general prefer composition to inheritance.
>   Only inheritance suffers from the fragile base class problem, in which
>   you can inadvertently break subclasses by changing a superclass.

To me it is unclear. Can anyone show an example of such a situation, preferably with some code?

Comment: In case you want to look at it from the very beginning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w2Pz3XodH0  - relationship between the philosophy and programming OOP. no scala specifically though. (educational)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class) is general to all systems that support inheritance. It means that changes to your supertype (the class you are inheriting from) can get you unexpected results : change makes you break your assumptions on your base class. See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921397/what-is-the-fragile-base-class-problem) for explanation & examples.

By contrast Scala exports posterior additions to parent classes to exterior, independent traits, that you can add to a subtype using Mixin Composition. See [this example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/117), and consider "`RichIterator`" as change that you would like to effect on the base `AbsIterator`, once it has been defined. See how the mixin doesn't change anything of the parent, yet is still easily reusable in a subtype ?